# db.collection.remove() function not working on MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I just had a quick question about a problem I have been running into with MongoDB using Node.js. I am not able to delete all the documents in a collection using the command "db.users.remove({})". I know that the collection name is correct. I have run this in the terminal and although it seems as though the command was run, it did not delete all the documents in the collection. When I run it using a post request, it just says db is not defined, which makes no sense to me. The reason why I have no query string is that I want to delete all the documents. I have included all my code below, but if a person can tell me perhaps a better way to delete all the documents in a collection or a solution to my problem I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

```
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const checkTypes = require('checktypes-js')
const schema = require('../schemas/user')
const usersDB = require('../models/usersModel')
const { Types } = require('mongoose')

const fileQuery = "logs.txt"


router.post('/new', (req, res) => {
    checkTypes(req.body, schema.user, async (err, passedObject) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
            return res.json({errors: err})
        } else {
            const existingUserEmail = await usersDB.findOne({email: passedObject.email})
            const existingUserUsername = await usersDB.findOne({username: passedObject.username})
            console.log(existingUserEmail, existingUserUsername)
            if (existingUserEmail || existingUserUsername){
                return res.json({error: "A user with that email or username exists too!"})
            }
            passedObject.active = true
            const addedUser = await usersDB.create(passedObject)
            res.send(addedUser)
            const fileMessage = "\nNew user with username of " + existingUserUsername + ' has been added on ' + new Date()
            console.log(fileMessage)
            return fs.appendFile(fileQuery, fileMessage, function (err){
                if (err){
                    console.error(err)
                }
                res.send("The file has been successfully written to!")
            })
        } 
    })
})

router.post('/update', (req, res) => {
    checkTypes(req.body, schema.user, async (err, passedObject) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
            return res.json({errors: err})
        } else {
            const {_id, ...update} = passedObject
            if(!Types.ObjectId.isValid(_id)){
                return res.json({error: 'Invalid id supplied'})
            }
            const updatedUser = await usersDB.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, update, {new: true})
            if (!updatedUser){
                return res.json({error: "Could not find the user with that ID!"})
            } else {
                res.json(updatedUser)
                const fileMessage = "\nUpdate user with id of " + _id + ' on ' + new Date()
                console.log(fileMessage)
                return fs.appendFile(fileQuery, fileMessage, function (err){
                    if (err){
                        console.error(err)
                    }
                    res.send("The file has been successfully written to!")
                })
            }
        }
    })
})

router.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
    checkTypes(req.body, schema.user, async (err, passedObject) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
            res.json({error: err})
        } else {
            const {_id, ...deleteObj} = passedObject
            console.log(_id)
            if(!Types.ObjectId.isValid(_id)){
                return res.json({error: 'Invalid id supplied'})
            }
            const deleteUser = usersDB.findByIdAndRemove({_id: _id}, function (err){
                if (err){
                    return res.send("A user with that ID is not defined!")
                } else {
                    res.send("The object has been deleted!")
                    const fileMessage = "\nUser with id of " + _id + ' has been delete on ' + new Date()
                    console.log(fileMessage)
                    return fs.appendFile(fileQuery, fileMessage, function (err){
                        if (err){
                            console.error(err)
                        }
                        res.send("The file has been successfully written to!")
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
})

router.post("/deleteAll", (req, res) => {
    db.users.remove({})
    res.send("All documents have been deleted!")
    const fileMessage = "\nAll documents in the remindars collection have been deleted on " + new Date()
        console.log(fileMessage)
        return fs.appendFile(fileQuery, fileMessage, function (err){
            if (err){
                console.error(err)
            }
            res.send("The file has been successfully written to!")
        })
})

router.post('/testFile', (req, res) => {
    const fileMessage = "\nThe file writing script was tested on " + new Date()
    console.log(fileMessage)
    return fs.appendFile(fileQuery, fileMessage, function (err){
        if (err){
            console.error(err)
        }
        res.send("The file has been successfully written to!")
    })
})

router.post('/clearFile', (req, res) => {
    const fileMessage = ""
    console.log(fileMessage)
    return fs.writeFile(fileQuery, fileMessage, function (err){
        if (err){
            console.error(err)
        }
        res.send("The file has been successfully written to!")
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Well, the code usually doesn't lie, and it's the same in your case. You don't have `db` variable anywhere in your code :) But `db.[collection].remove({})` in the Mongo Shell should totally work.

Comment: seeing the first method, this should delete all users: `usersDB.remove({}, callback)`

Comment: Wait so do I exactly type "db.[collection].remove({})" in the mongo shell? Or do I replace "[collection]" with the name of my collection, which is "users". If I do have to replace it, then that is exactly what I did in the mongo shell before but it didn't work. I typed in "db.users.remove({})".

Comment: `db.users.remove({})` is asynchronous, and needs to be exec'd to get a promise that you can await if you don't provide a callback.  Follow Akrion's answer to await the remove operation, especially before writing out `res.send("All documents have been deleted!")` because it just isn't true yet, until you await the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
const usersDB = require('../models/usersModel')
```

Which is your mongoose model but you are calling `db.users.remove({})`.

Use your model like everywhere else in your code:

```
const result = await usersDB.remove({}).exec()
```

or:

```
Author.remove({}).then(x => {
  console.log(x)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Have a great day!